# Помогите разобрать код по полочкам для понимания написанного

Tags: php, массивы

Из изначальных массивов выведен новый массив с наименованием животных только из 2-х слов. Далее, выведены названия животных, где 1ое слово остается на своем месте, а 2ое рандомно присваивается к другому. Помогите разжевать код, для чего, зачем. Больше интересует вывод массива с наименованиями в 2 слова.

```
<?php
$continents = [
    'Africa' => [
        'African elephant',
        'Crocodile',
        'Spotted hyena',
        'Zebra',
        'Chimpanzee',
        'Python',
        'Scorpio',
        'Canna',
    ],
    'Eurasia' => [
        'Tapir',
        'Snow leopard',
        'Varan',
        'Big panda',
        'Capercaillie',
        'Pheasant',
        'Mantis',
        'Brown bear'
    ],
    'Antarctida' => [
        'Aptenodytes forsteri',
        'Pygoscelis adeliae',
        'Mirounga angustirostris',
        'Eubalaena australis',
        'Phocoena dioptrica'
    ]
];

$name_two_words = [];

foreach($continents as $continent => $animals){
    foreach($animals as $animal){
        $all_animals= [] ;
        $anim = explode(' ', $animal);
        $all_animals[]=$anim;

        foreach($all_animals as $k){
            if(count($k) === 2){
                $comma_separated = implode(",", $k);
                $str = str_replace(',', ' ', $comma_separated);
                $name_two_words[]=$str;
            }
        }
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($name_two_words);
echo '<pre>';


foreach($name_two_words as $name){
    $parts = explode(' ', $name);
    $first[] = $parts[0];
    $second[] = $parts[1];
}

$random_first_word = [];

while (count($random_first_word) < count($name_two_words)){
   $proverka = $first[rand(0, count($name_two_words)-1)];
    if (!in_array($proverka, $random_first_word)) {
        array_push($random_first_word, $proverka);
    }
}

//var_dump($random_first_word);

$random_second_word = [];

while (count($random_second_word) < count($name_two_words)){
    $proverka = $second[rand(0, count($name_two_words)-1)];
    if (!in_array($proverka, $random_second_word)) {
        array_push($random_second_word, $proverka);
    }
}

//var_dump($random_second_word );

$final_result = [];

for($i = 0; $i < count($name_two_words); $i++){
    $final_result[]= $random_first_word[$i] . ' ' . $random_second_word[$i];  
}

var_dump($final_result);
```

Comment: что именно в приведенном коде Вам непонятно ? обычный перебор и rand() для получения случайного первого и второго слова.

Comment: Дело в том, что только начал учить php. Непонятен в принципе код, зачем это делается для чего, зачем пишется такая последовательность. Хотелось бы разбора построчного. Больше непонятна часть с перебором, как это происходит, в голове для себя не могу понять.

Comment: *зачем это делается для чего, зачем пишется такая последовательность?* - для получения желаемого результата. Уточните пожалуйста, Вы уже изучили перебирающие методы `foreach()`, `while()`, `for()`,  также функции `count()`, `in_array()`, `array_push()`, `in_array()` и `rand()`. Если нет, изучите, потом посмотрите на код и подумайте, что осталось непонятным. Если уже изучили, вернемся к вопросу *что именно непонятно в приведенном коде ?*

Comment: Для php есть вся документация на русском с примерами http://php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php Там же поиск по функциям.

Comment: $anim = explode(' ', $animal);  $all_animals[]=$anim;
 Например это. Да я изучал но видимо не совсем хорошо понимаю как это все используется, займусь сегодня повторно.

Comment: `$anim = explode(' ', $animal);` присваивает `$anim` массив, полученный разбиением строки `$animal` при помощи разделителя в виде пробела. `$all_animals[]=$anim;` - добавляет массив `$anim` в массив `$all_animals`